# Node function in AWS throws "missing ) after argument list" error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda function (Node.js 12.x) in AWS so SNS messages are pushed to Slack from our ETL tool Matillion.

```
console.log('Loading function');

const https = require('https');
const url = require('url');
const slack_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1MJBHQ95/B01DQ60NUR2/....';
const slack_req_opts = url.parse(slack_url);
slack_req_opts.method = 'POST';
slack_req_opts.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
        (event.Records || []).forEach(function (rec) {
                if (rec.Sns) {
                    var req = https.request(slack_req_opts, function (res) {
                        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                            context.succeed('sns posted to slack');
                        }
                        else {
                            context.fail('status code: ' + res.statusCode);
                        }
                    });

                    req.on('error', function (e) {
                        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
                        context.fail(e.message);
                    });

                    req.write(JSON.stringify({ text: `${rec.Sns.Message}` }));

                        req.end();
                    }
                });
        };
```

The function will fail with a `missing ) after argument list` syntax error. I run it thru a linter in Sublime and it throws an error on `require` and `exports` being undefined.

My research shows several challenges:

- I may need a file called eslint.rc but I am unclear why I need to put
  in.
- The use of "require" and "exports" appears deprecated.

Can someone please give me pointers how what to focus on to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: this works locally ? if possible add full trace of error which you can find out in CloudWatch log or lambda execution log

Comment: It does not work locally. "Require" and "Exports" are server-based.

Comment: @user14579431 What do you mean "require and exports are server based""? There is no reason you couldn't test this code on your local computer.

Comment: `Error    require is not defined. (no-undef)` and `exports is not defined. (no-undef)` are the errors I get when I run my code locally. That's why I assumed both functions are server-based.

Answer (score 3):

You made a syntax mistake in your code.

```
req.write(JSON.stringify({ text: `${rec.Sns.Message}` }));
req.end();
```

Need to add `)` before `;` in your req.write() statement.

Comment: Fixed typo (thank you). Now I get a new error message `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Axios, it will make your life easier:

```js
console.log('Loading function');

const axios = require('axios');
const url = require('url');
const slack_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1MJBHQ95/B01DQ60NUR2/....';

exports.handler = async (event, context) {
   (event.Records || []).forEach(function(rec) {
      if (rec.Sns) {
         axios.post(slack_url, {
            text: rec.Sns.Message
         }, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }).done(r => {
           context.succeed('sns posted to slack');
         }).catch(e => {
           context.fail('status code: ' + e.statusCode);
     });
});
```

Notice that in your code, after 1 sns event he end the invocation, not running all, to run all of them you need to wait for all requests to be done (can use `Promise.all` for example)

Also, be aware that sns can send directly to HTTPS without any code
https://aws.amazon.com/sns/features/

By the way, you can use an external monitoring tool that will show you exactly the outgoing request + all payload as `Lumigo` (As a disclaimer I work for a company named lumigo)

Comment: Your suggestion fails to run in AWS with a `errorMessage:SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error message.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed my issue:

1. I added the following statement at the top of my file `/* eslint-env node, common */`
2. I re-deployed my function.

I believe the redeployment of the function did the trick.